# Differing behavior in VSCode with Maven on PC and Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, visual-studio-code, javafx

We're using Maven in VSCode to develop with JavaFX. Maven works fine with VSCode on PCs but we can't use the "Play" button or "Run Without Debugging" on Macs.

java 19.0.1
javafx 19
maven 3.8.6
VSCode 1.74.1

On a PC, we get this:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_et8lcjrjl0fge41txqyx61dgy.argfile' '-m' 'activities/activities.HelloFX'
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp "C:\\Users\\username\\SoftDevII\\2225.124.MavenStarter\\target\\classes;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-controls\\19\\javafx-controls-19.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-controls\\19\\javafx-controls-19-win.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-graphics\\19\\javafx-graphics-19.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-graphics\\19\\javafx-graphics-19-win.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-base\\19\\javafx-base-19.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-base\\19\\javafx-base-19-win.jar" -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp "C:\\Users\\username\\SoftDevII\\2225.124.MavenStarter\\target\\classes;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-controls\\19\\javafx-controls-19.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-controls\\19\\javafx-controls-19-win.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-graphics\\19\\javafx-graphics-19.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-graphics\\19\\javafx-graphics-19-win.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-base\\19\\javafx-base-19.jar;C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\org\\openjfx\\javafx-base\\19\\javafx-base-19-win.jar"
```

And on Macs we get this, a very different invocation:

```
[Running] cd "/124-2225/2225.124.MavenStarter/src/main/java/activities/" && javac HelloFX.java && java HelloFX

HelloFX.java:3: error: package javafx.application does not exist
import javafx.application.Application; HelloFX.java:4: error: package javafx.stage does not exist
import javafx.stage.Stage;
                   ^
HelloFX.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
public class HelloFX extends Application {
                             ^
  symbol: class Application
HelloFX.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
                      ^
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class HelloFX
HelloFX.java:8: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
HelloFX.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        launch(args);
        ^
  symbol:   method launch(String[])
  location: class HelloFX
```

However, we can run it from the command line if we include what we already have set in VSCode's settings.json, "java.debug.settings.vmArgs":

```
java --module-path /Java/javafx-sdk-19/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media activities/HelloFX.java
```

In addition, we can successfully execute the single file from Maven's javafx plugin, but we will have multiple application classes so that's not a good solution. It *seems* like a VSCode issue, but we have no idea where or why Macs and PCs are so different.

Comment: Those are compile errors (generated by [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/javac.html)) not runtime errors (generated by `java`).  That indicates that the compiler is not finding the JavaFX modules, so you are not providing the correct `--module-path` to the compiler, or not adding the required modules via `--add-modules` (the later is required if you don't provide a `module-info.java`).  See [Getting started: JavaFX and Visual Studio Code](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for setup of VSCode for JavaFX.

Comment: If using Maven, I don't understand why you would manually set paths to JavaFX in a separately downloaded JavaFX SDK.  The JavaFX SDK should not be necessary because maven will download and provide all of the modules you needed (if your maven project is correctly configured).

Comment: If you'll read the original question more closely you'll note that these commands are the output produced when pressing the "play" (Run) button in VS Code. On Windows VS Code uses a -cp argument to include the path to all of the required libraries. On macOS it does not. VS Code does not try to use Maven to run the application when using "play".